# Problem in solving the following inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

I can't find a formal proof for this inequality:

$$
q \ln(1-q)- q \ln q - \ln (1-q) \leq \ln2 \\ 0\lt q \lt\ 1
$$

Using the exponentials I found this expression:

$$
\frac{(1-q)^{(q-1)}}{q^{q}} \leq 2
$$

but I think that this is not the right procedure for a right proof. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You might consider \ln rather than ln in your Latex.

Comment: What are you given and what are you trying to prove?  Are you given he log inequation and what to prove $0< q< 1$ or are you give $0< q< 1$ and want to prove the log inequality?  Or something else.

Comment: @Gmp Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have that

$$q \ln(1-q)- q \ln q - \ln (1-q) \leq \ln 2\iff -(1-q)\ln(1-q)-q\ln q\le \ln 2$$

and

$$f(x)=-(1-x)\ln (1-x)-x\ln x\implies f'(x)=\ln (1-x)-\ln x=0 \implies x=\frac12$$

Answer (score 0):

Often these problems are easier with an intuitive feel for why they might be true. In my case, that almost always boils down to a picture describing the problem. This isn't a proof in its own right, but it can help provide intuition for the proof's strategy. In my case, I started by graphing the difference between the left-hand-side and the right-hand-side as follows.
[image]

This numerical evidence strongly indicates that there is a unique local extremum at $q=\frac12$, and we might very well be able to use that in our proof. In practice, it turned out that the numerical evidence was correct, and a proof revolving around local extrema works just fine.

Our strategy then is to try to find the maxima (if they exist) for your function. If we define $$f(q)=q\ln(1-q)-q\ln(q)-\ln(1-q)-\ln(2)$$ then this amounts to finding where $f'(q)=0$, since $f$ is differentiable on the entire specified domain. If we find a unique local maximum and no minima, the local maximum must be a global maximum. We can readily compute that $$f'(q)=\ln\left(\frac{1-q}q\right),$$ and setting that equal to $0$ yields the unique solution $q=\frac12$. A little algebra allows us to conclude $f\left(\frac12\right)=0$, as desired. By checking the second derivative $$f''(q)=\frac1{q(q-1)}$$ we note that this is a local maximum rather than a local minimum. Since there are no other local extrema, $f(q)$ must be strictly less than $f\left(\frac12\right)$ for any $q\in(0,1)\setminus\{\frac12\}.$ Hence, $f(q)\leq0$ on the entire domain, as desired.